# Is this a reasonable speed for mongodb? Or can i reasonable increase the perfomance?

Tags: performance, mongodb

I have a mongodb-collection with 15Million entries

the documents look like this

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53dc6267a004ccb072e62223"),
  "type" : "way",
  "id" : 92974485,
  "closed" : true,
  "tags" : {
    "building" : "yes"
  },
  "attributes" : {
    "uid" : "67792",
    "timestamp" : "2011-01-02T01:03:18Z",
    "id" : "92974485",
    "user" : "UncleBob",
    "changeset" : "6834391",
    "version" : "1"
  },
  "bb" : {
    "top" : 50.1851254,
    "bottom" : 50.1847791,
    "left" : 8.2829808,
    "right" : 8.2837873
  },
  "area" : 2.792909499972435E-07,
  "outers" : [[{
        "x" : 8.2830627,
        "y" : 50.1847791
      }, {
        "x" : 8.2837873,
        "y" : 50.1850276
      }, {
        "x" : 8.2837054,
        "y" : 50.1851254
      }, {
        "x" : 8.2829808,
        "y" : 50.1848769
      }, {
        "x" : 8.2830627,
        "y" : 50.1847791
      }]],
  "inners" : [[]]
}
```

the index is created like this

```
BasicDBObject boundsIndex = new BasicDBObject();
boundsIndex.put("bb.left", 1);
boundsIndex.put("bb.right", 1);
boundsIndex.put("bb.top", 1);
boundsIndex.put("bb.bottom", 1);
geoCollection.createIndex(boundsIndex);
```

now i'm running querys like this

```
> db.geos.find({ "$and" : [ { "bb.top" : { "$gte" : 50.1800537109375}} , { "bb.bottom" : { "$lte" : 50.185546875}} , { "bb.left" : { "$lte" : 8.294677734375}} , { "bb.right" : { "$gte" : 8.28369140625}} , { "type" : { "$ne" : "node"}}]}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor bb.left_1_bb.right_1_bb.top_1_bb.bottom_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 82,
        "nscannedObjects" : 289,
        "nscanned" : 741908,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 492,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1004432,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 96,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 2687,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "bb.left" : [
                        [
                                -Infinity,
                                8.294677734375
                        ]
                ],
                "bb.right" : [
                        [
                                8.28369140625,
                                Infinity
                        ]
                ],
                "bb.top" : [
                        [
                                50.1800537109375,
                                Infinity
                        ]
                ],
                "bb.bottom" : [
                        [
                                -Infinity,
                                50.185546875
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "wutze-PC:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
>
```

which returns in this case 82 documents.

But the query takes ~1800ms.

1800ms would be bearable , but when i run 5 of these query simultaneous it takes about 10000ms. This is no more acceptable, i've big plans

Is it possible to increase the performance or is this the maximum speed i could expect?

Since there is an easy to use index i would expect faster results.

I'm running on mongodb 2.6 on windows with a Intel i5-4670K and 8GB ram... means no low level system

EDIT1: Query reordered

```
> db.geos.find({ "$and" : [ { "bb.left" : { "$lte" : 8.294677734375}} , { "bb.right" : { "$gte" : 8.28369140625}} , { "bb.top" : { "$gte" : 50.1800537109375}} , { "bb.bottom" : { "$lte" : 50.185546875}}]}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor bb.left_1_bb.right_1_bb.top_1_bb.bottom_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 289,
        "nscannedObjects" : 289,
        "nscanned" : 741908,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 289,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 741908,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 14,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 2098,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "bb.left" : [
                        [
                                -Infinity,
                                8.294677734375
                        ]
                ],
                "bb.right" : [
                        [
                                8.28369140625,
                                Infinity
                        ]
                ],
                "bb.top" : [
                        [
                                50.1800537109375,
                                Infinity
                        ]
                ],
                "bb.bottom" : [
                        [
                                -Infinity,
                                50.185546875
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "wutze-PC:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
>
```

EDIT 2:

```
> db.geos.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "local.geos"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "id_1",
                "ns" : "local.geos"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "type" : 1
                },
                "name" : "type_1",
                "ns" : "local.geos"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "closed" : 1
                },
                "name" : "closed_1",
                "ns" : "local.geos"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "tags.natural" : 1
                },
                "name" : "tags.natural_1",
                "ns" : "local.geos"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "tags.landuse" : 1
                },
                "name" : "tags.landuse_1",
                "ns" : "local.geos"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "tags.name" : 1
                },
                "name" : "tags.name_1",
                "ns" : "local.geos"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "bb.left" : 1,
                        "bb.right" : 1,
                        "bb.top" : 1,
                        "bb.bottom" : 1
                },
                "name" : "bb.left_1_bb.right_1_bb.top_1_bb.bottom_1",
                "ns" : "local.geos"
        }
]
>
```

EDIT 3 without and

```
> db.geos.find({"bb.left": { "$lte" : 8.294677734375}, "bb.right": { "$gte" : 8.28369140625}, "bb.top": { "$gte" : 50.1800537109375}, "bb.bottom": { "$lte" : 50.185546875}}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor bb.left_1_bb.right_1_bb.top_1_bb.bottom_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 289,
        "nscannedObjects" : 289,
        "nscanned" : 741908,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 289,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 741908,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 13,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 1866,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "bb.left" : [
                        [
                                -Infinity,
                                8.294677734375
                        ]
                ],
                "bb.right" : [
                        [
                                8.28369140625,
                                Infinity
                        ]
                ],
                "bb.top" : [
                        [
                                50.1800537109375,
                                Infinity
                        ]
                ],
                "bb.bottom" : [
                        [
                                -Infinity,
                                50.185546875
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "wutze-PC:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
>
```

EDIT serverstats

```
> db.stats()
{
        "db" : "local",
        "collections" : 5,
        "objects" : 15604808,
        "avgObjSize" : 571.5683889221834,
        "dataSize" : 8919214968,
        "storageSize" : 9316446192,
        "numExtents" : 29,
        "indexes" : 15,
        "indexSize" : 6654708032,
        "fileSize" : 19251855360,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalSize" : 0
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
>> db.serverStatus()
{
        "host" : "wutze-PC",
        "version" : "2.6.2",
        "process" : "mongod",
        "pid" : NumberLong(6328),
        "uptime" : 72455,
        "uptimeMillis" : NumberLong(72454818),
        "uptimeEstimate" : 37621,
        "localTime" : ISODate("2014-08-03T17:17:39.439Z"),
        "asserts" : {
                "regular" : 0,
                "warning" : 0,
                "msg" : 0,
                "user" : 0,
                "rollovers" : 0
        },
        "backgroundFlushing" : {
                "flushes" : 628,
                "total_ms" : 2828685,
                "average_ms" : 4504.275477707007,
                "last_ms" : 40,
                "last_finished" : ISODate("2014-08-03T17:17:22.560Z")
        },
        "connections" : {
                "current" : 2,
                "available" : 999998,
                "totalCreated" : NumberLong(22)
        },
        "cursors" : {
                "note" : "deprecated, use server status metrics",
                "clientCursors_size" : 0,
                "totalOpen" : 0,
                "pinned" : 0,
                "totalNoTimeout" : 0,
                "timedOut" : 0
        },
        "dur" : {
                "commits" : 30,
                "journaledMB" : 0,
                "writeToDataFilesMB" : 0,
                "compression" : 0,
                "commitsInWriteLock" : 0,
                "earlyCommits" : 0,
                "timeMs" : {
                        "dt" : 3060,
                        "prepLogBuffer" : 0,
                        "writeToJournal" : 0,
                        "writeToDataFiles" : 0,
                        "remapPrivateView" : 0
                }
        },
        "extra_info" : {
                "note" : "fields vary by platform",
                "page_faults" : 129486579,
                "usagePageFileMB" : 158,
                "totalPageFileMB" : 16162,
                "availPageFileMB" : 10378,
                "ramMB" : 8081
        },
        "globalLock" : {
                "totalTime" : NumberLong("72454821000"),
                "lockTime" : NumberLong(1502088883),
                "currentQueue" : {
                        "total" : 0,
                        "readers" : 0,
                        "writers" : 0
                },
                "activeClients" : {
                        "total" : 0,
                        "readers" : 0,
                        "writers" : 0
                }
        },
        "indexCounters" : {
                "accesses" : 575367889,
                "hits" : 575367889,
                "misses" : 0,
                "resets" : 0,
                "missRatio" : 0
        },
        "locks" : {
                "." : {
                        "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                "R" : NumberLong(52755051),
                                "W" : NumberLong(1502088883)
                        },
                        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                "R" : NumberLong(247643851),
                                "W" : NumberLong(42199701)
                        }
                },
                "admin" : {
                        "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(369986),
                                "w" : NumberLong(0)
                        },
                        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(864),
                                "w" : NumberLong(0)
                        }
                },
                "local" : {
                        "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(1638453258),
                                "w" : NumberLong("3237777167")
                        },
                        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong("2804943595"),
                                "w" : NumberLong(739358049)
                        }
                },
                "test" : {
                        "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(11863),
                                "w" : NumberLong(0)
                        },
                        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(821),
                                "w" : NumberLong(0)
                        }
                }
        },
        "network" : {
                "bytesIn" : 8620819599,
                "bytesOut" : 7663424729,
                "numRequests" : 17320018
        },
        "opcounters" : {
                "insert" : 15604773,
                "query" : 17290096,
                "update" : 0,
                "delete" : 0,
                "getmore" : 4,
                "command" : 16188
        },
        "opcountersRepl" : {
                "insert" : 0,
                "query" : 0,
                "update" : 0,
                "delete" : 0,
                "getmore" : 0,
                "command" : 0
        },
        "recordStats" : {
                "accessesNotInMemory" : 3448647,
                "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 1689,
                "admin" : {
                        "accessesNotInMemory" : 0,
                        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 0
                },
                "local" : {
                        "accessesNotInMemory" : 3448647,
                        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 1689
                },
                "test" : {
                        "accessesNotInMemory" : 0,
                        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 0
                }
        },
        "writeBacksQueued" : false,
        "mem" : {
                "bits" : 64,
                "resident" : 172,
                "virtual" : 36932,
                "supported" : true,
                "mapped" : 18376,
                "mappedWithJournal" : 36752
        },
        "metrics" : {
                "cursor" : {
                        "timedOut" : NumberLong(0),
                        "open" : {
                                "noTimeout" : NumberLong(0),
                                "pinned" : NumberLong(0),
                                "total" : NumberLong(0)
                        }
                },
                "document" : {
                        "deleted" : NumberLong(0),
                        "inserted" : NumberLong(15604773),
                        "returned" : NumberLong(17275473),
                        "updated" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "getLastError" : {
                        "wtime" : {
                                "num" : 0,
                                "totalMillis" : 0
                        },
                        "wtimeouts" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "operation" : {
                        "fastmod" : NumberLong(0),
                        "idhack" : NumberLong(0),
                        "scanAndOrder" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "queryExecutor" : {
                        "scanned" : NumberLong(5798761),
                        "scannedObjects" : NumberLong(1601)
                },
                "record" : {
                        "moves" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "repl" : {
                        "apply" : {
                                "batches" : {
                                        "num" : 0,
                                        "totalMillis" : 0
                                },
                                "ops" : NumberLong(0)
                        },
                        "buffer" : {
                                "count" : NumberLong(0),
                                "maxSizeBytes" : 268435456,
                                "sizeBytes" : NumberLong(0)
                        },
                        "network" : {
                                "bytes" : NumberLong(0),
                                "getmores" : {
                                        "num" : 0,
                                        "totalMillis" : 0
                                },
                                "ops" : NumberLong(0),
                                "readersCreated" : NumberLong(0)
                        },
                        "preload" : {
                                "docs" : {
                                        "num" : 0,
                                        "totalMillis" : 0
                                },
                                "indexes" : {
                                        "num" : 0,
                                        "totalMillis" : 0
                                }
                        }
                },
                "storage" : {
                        "freelist" : {
                                "search" : {
                                        "bucketExhausted" : NumberLong(0),
                                        "requests" : NumberLong(16418927),
                                        "scanned" : NumberLong(32837623)
                                }
                        }
                },
                "ttl" : {
                        "deletedDocuments" : NumberLong(0),
                        "passes" : NumberLong(626)
                }
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
>
```

Comment: That query can only use the leftmost part of the index (bb.left). Consider using the geospatial indices. You might also get away with index intersection.

Comment: The indexes can definitely fit the RAM. Try to not use compound indexes (single indexes per `bb.****`). It might also be an I/O problem. Does the server have an SSD? By the way why don't you use a geo index with polygons?

Comment: i've tried the geoindex before but it was more slow and too fussy for my data... i'm trying now to create an index with only bb.left. Why can the index only use bb.left?

Comment: @Diolor i moved the data to an ssd-disk... but it takes 1800ms too ... it seems not to be an io problem

Answer (score 1):

Some things to note:

- You *are* running MongoDB on a fairly low system for that purpose. For the compound index alone there are 75M values. Another 30M for the _id index others not counted. Since you didn't say anything about it, I assume a spinning disk. All in all this sounds like a desktop configuration, so the OS takes away it's share of the system resources as well. Talking of the OS: Windows file systems are up to 4 times slower than ext4 or XFS. Maybe there is place for optimization, as well.
- I honestly doubt that a 2D search with[$geoWithin and $box](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/box/#box) is slower than a chained lte/gte index search.
- Contrary to what has been told, the index was used. The 289 scanned documents were those which had to bee returned with all their values, and since no [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-projection) was used and the data wasn't available in the index, the query wasn't a so called [covered query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#create-indexes-that-support-covered-queries).

Using projection and compound indices to create a covered query might dramatically speed up searches. A two step retrieval with a covered query containing the _id field and the subsequent retrieval of the doc(s) may be the valid way to go here,too. The index to create would be `DB.geos.ensureIndex({"bb":"2d","_id":1})` (with adaption to the storage of the bounding boxes, of course) and the according query would be `db.geos.find({"bb":{$geoWithin:{$box: [[ xOfBottomLeft, yOfBottomLeft],[xOfTopRight, yOfTopRight]]}}},{"bb":1})`. The projection should make this a covered query, and the `_id` field is returned by default. Now, you can iterate over the result set or get the complete documents in one query using the `$or` operator. Using the 2d query may however speed up your search enough that you don't have to use projection at all and retrieve the documents with the first query.

*Edit:* You really shouldn't use the local database for storing your collections. The local database isn't replicated in a replica set (hence the name local). I am not sure wether it can be sharded, too.

Comment: yes its a desktop environment, i already tried to run the data directory on my ssd, and it took exactly the same time, so i don't think that it is an io problem. Now i tried just to fetch the object id's by adding a second paramter to my find function ",{_id:1}" but its still the same speed. Local databse is ok i'm in the proof of concept phase. I just cannot imagine why this is that slow the querys are perfect indexable, i could write a faster solution by myself

Comment: Actually, what most likely happens is that mongod is hitting the filesystem too often because the indices are not fitting into the remaining RAM. When swapping starts, mongod gets really slow. Please post the output of db.stats() for your database and db.serverStatus().

Comment: ive added the output to the question 3GB of 8GB of the physical ram are free at the moment which does not change while running the query

Comment: The output states differently. The index size is more than 6GB and you have a high number of page faults, indicating that during an index search, the disk is hit extremely often (4 times per operation on average, although most of them were soft page faults, meaning the page file being accessed frequently). It is Windows extremely counterproductive way to page as much as possible. At the time of you issuing that command, mongo used 158MB of the page file. The only thing you can do IMHO except scaling up: use the 2d index. Chaining lte/gte is very bad performance wise.

Comment: the 2d index (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/) only supports points, as i can see in the docs, you mean i should save the center-point of bb and make my querys with $near?

Comment: Read my comment again. Actually, there is an example for the $box in a 2d index...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58576/discussion-between-markus-w-mahlberg-and-wutzebaer).